# PHP / MySQL lecture allocation

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP, MySQL to develop a website to be used in an educational institution.

One function of this is to allocate lectures when creating a batch. To allocate lectures to the starting batch, system will prompt available lectures based on their availability and qualifications. Then the course coordinator will take the decision.

My problem is how to check the availability of the lecture on a particular week day given time slot.(time slot is varying not fixed durations)

I am planning to keep lecture schedules in a table where it shows lecture_Id, Batch_Id, day, start_time, end_time, start_day , end_day.

Then when availability checking I need to write a complex query to check the available lecture_Id's. I couldn't figure out it yet.

Is there any other smart ways to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend changing the four time fields into two DATE fields in the MySQL, that gives you less complexity with _all the fun!_

Answer (score 0):

The way you're proposing to store the info is the first way I'd think of doing it - the complex query isn't so bad though.

So if I understand correctly, you have lectures stored in another table, with a one - to -many relationship with your lecture_schedules table?
If so, this will get the lecture details for a given time range.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM lecture_schedules 
         INNER JOIN lectures USING(lecture_id) 
         WHERE start_day<=DAY(yourstarttime) AND end_day>=DAY(yourendtime) 
         AND start_time<=yourstarttime AND end_time>=yourendtime;
```

Note you will need to edit table names and column names to reflect your actual schema, and replace `yourstarttime` and `yourendtime` with the time range values.

Hope this helps

EDIT:
This query makes several assumptions about the columns and datatypes of those columns in your schema - don't just copy & paste and expect it to work first time :)